# How to delete Ktor server multipart data temp files after responding to call

Tags: multipartform-data, ktor

I'm running a Ktor server on Ubuntu 20.04 which receives files through POST using multipart/form-data. I receive the data as follows:

```
    val multiPart = call.receiveMultipart()
    val part = multiPart.readPart()
```

This works, but everytime a file is uploaded this way, a file (e.g. `file-upload11775280475526112.tmp`) also appears in the `/tmp` folder. Is there any way to make the Ktor server delete these files after responding to the corresponding POST call? The size of these files really adds up over time. I'm currently clearing them using a cron job once in a while, but ideally I'd like the server to clean up after itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `dispose` method on a `PartData` object to release all resources associated with the part. Here is an example:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 3030) {
    routing {
        post("/") {
            val part = call.receiveMultipart().readPart()

            if (part is PartData.FormItem || part is PartData.BinaryItem) {
                part.dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}.start(wait = true)
```